# Modifying BuildConfig.java using ant

Tags: android

Is there a way I can control parameters in BuildConfig.java using ant? Something similar to BuildConfigField in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

try this post: [Android - use ant to create build configurations that change configuration values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032078/android-use-ant-to-create-build-configurations-that-change-configuration-value)

Found a tutorial which goes through all the details of using ant to automate a build system, to create and use build configurations, as well as to build the release project with one command. Here it is: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html